# Service fabric deployment issues

Tags: c#, .net, windows, azure, azure-service-fabric

Deployment issues when running the service fabric app. The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

1. Moved my repo close to the drive. C:\Repo
2. Updated the registry LongPathsEnabled to 1 to allow for long paths.

Error    MSB4184    The expression "[System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath(pkg\Debug\XYXYXWorkerPackage\Code\Agent\Extensions\AzureSecurityPack\.msmanifest)" cannot be evaluated. The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.    XYX.ServiceFabric.App    C:\NuGetPackages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.6.7\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.targets

Not sure if I can tweak to change the deployment path?

Comment: https://betanews.com/2016/05/29/long-paths-windows-10/

Comment: How did you deploy the app?

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping that you are having problems while deploying the application to Azure.

And if that is the case, try the below options if you haven't already and see if this solves your problem.

Try adding the following line to the first property group of your Windows Azure Visual Studio Project file (*.ccproj):

```
<ServiceOutputDirectory>C:\Azure\</ServiceOutputDirectory>
```

Just be careful when you run this. because this folder will be deleted each time you create a package if it exists.

This setting seems to redirect the working folder for the package to a shorter base path, preventing the path too long.

Also take a look at the below blog. 
[Resolving "The Path is too long after being fully qualified" Error Message](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jnak/2010/01/14/windows-azure-resolving-the-path-is-too-long-after-being-fully-qualified-error-message/)

Comment: I did couple of changes: Moved to C:\ renamed my repo to 2 characters, Enabled win32 long paths in the group policy editor and the what was given in the[Resolving "The Path is too long after being fully qualified" Error Message][1] . Reboot fixed the problem. Not sure which one really fixed it.

  [1]: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jnak/2010/01/14/windows-azure-resolving-the-path-is-too-long-after-being-fully-qualified-error-message/

Comment: That's great. Glad the above article/ reboot helped resolve your issue.